# What's a good OODB option for .Net?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, oop

I'm developing a totally object-oriented application and I'm annoyed with the hard-work to implement objects data persistence in ER databases. I've heard about OO databases, and I'd like to know about a good option for using with .Net framework (integration, tools, documentation, reliability, etc.). Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you are looking for an OO database engine and not for a good and easy to use ORM? What is the issue with using EF or NHibernate with either SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL or whatever other database engine? Totally OO application does not mean the database cannot be any of the above.

Comment: No, I'm not sure if I want to use OODB because I haven't ever experienced it. I had considered using NHibernate, but I didn't think that's so easy. Then I considered to use some OODB, which would fit for my case. But is not a decision (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/), a document database written in .NET for .NET developers.

Answer (score 1):

[JOOB](http://www.joobworld.com) is a high performance OODB built for .NET. JOOB is very reliable, and has a free developer and evaluation version available.